# How to run stored procedure 1000 times

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure that I'm using to populate a table with about 60 columns.  I have genereated 1000 exec statements that look like this:

```
exec PopulateCVCSTAdvancement 174, 213, 1, 0, 7365
exec PopulateCVCSTAdvancement 174, 214, 1, 0, 7365
exec PopulateCVCSTAdvancement 175, 213, 0, 0, 7365
```

Each time the stored procedure will be inserting anywhere from 1 to 3,000 records (usually around 2,000 records).  The "server" is running desktop hardware with 4 gigs of available memory on a server OS.  The problem I have is that after the first 10-15 executes of an average of 1-2 seconds each time, the next 10-15 seem to never finish.  Am I doing this correctly?  How should I do this?

Thanks!
Top 10 waiters:

```
LAZYWRITER_SLEEP
SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP
REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH
XE_TIMER_EVENT
FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT
CHECKPOINT_QUEUE
LOGMGR_QUEUE
SLEEP_TASK
BROKER_TO_FLUSH
BROKER_TASK_STOP
```

Comment: You need to find out what the bottleneck is. What does the waitstats DMV say?

Comment: There are over 400 rows in that table.  Anything specific I should post?

Comment: the figures in it are cumulative so take a snapshot into a temporary table then do the action that generates the long wait and then compare the two to see which Wait types have increased the most. (Or just reset the figures in the DMV to 0 with `DBCC SQLPERF("sys.dm_os_wait_stats",CLEAR);` if you don't have any monitoring tools relying on it)

Comment: The DMV details you added are pretty uninformative TBH. Can you rest the values to 0 then post the top 10 waits and the actual numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the cause was from a bug in my stored procedure when running with certain parameters.

Specifically, I had a cte that I joined back to another table, however, some of the join criteria from the cte contained null values and caused it to go on forever.  A simple `isnull()` in the cte select criteria solved the problem.  Thanks to all that helped.

P.S.  It took 4 minutes to run once I wrapped it in a transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Random thoughts:

1. Make sure your database size is large enough to take autogrow out of the equation. The default growth is 10% and it's possible that you are growing the database. This applies to both MDF and LDF.
2. As well as checking the LDF size, change the recovery model to SIMPLE too for the duration of the load
3. You may have parameter sniffing. Can you add the [optimise for unknown](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/) hint to the stored proc

Comment: Good tips.  Found the log was set to 10 percent autogrowth.  Checking on the others now.

Comment: Was already set to simple.  I also added with recompile to the sp.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a transaction - it will load significantly faster

Comment: Agreed, But I can't see why that would explain the sudden time difference (unless a checkpoint has kicked in maybe?)

Comment: (speaking for mysql), when wrapping in a transaction, the query is built fully and THEN executed (its optimized as much as possible).